# take control of cin in main()

Tags: c++, istream

Is there a way to take control of cin so I can test this function?

```
void foo() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
}
```

I would like to do

```
int main()
{
    // take control of cin and use a stringstream instead
    stringstream ss;
    1 >> ss;
    s >> foo(); // will for sure not work?
}
```

**Note:** for completeness here is the final code:

```
struct membuf : std::streambuf
{
    membuf(char* begin, char* end) {
        this->setg(begin, begin, end);
    }
};

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "3\0";
    membuf sbuf(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer));
    std::istream in(&sbuf); 
    foo(in);
}

void foo(std::istream& iss = std::cin)
{
    int n; // number of students
    iss >> n;
}
```

Comment: @Holt yes, that is correct. I have the source code so can change cin to something else if it is impossible,

Comment: @Damian Then your function should provide a parameter of type `istream&` and use that one for output, instead of using `cin` directly.

Comment: Good point as a plan B.. if I can't shadow over cin

Comment: Personally I would do what @πάνταῥεῖ suggests.  I would take in a `istream&` and default it to `cin`.  That way if you want the standard behavior you need to do nothing but If you need a different stream then you can pass it to the function.  Gives you ease of use plus flexibility.

Comment: Can you show me the code for this please?

Comment: @Damian If you want to test a program that uses the standard input, you can create "test input file" and redirect them to your program, this way you would not have to input them manually.

Comment: Yes, maybe I will do that instead.. @Holt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for taking the stream as a parameter and defaulting to `cin`:

```
void foo(std::istream& iss = std::cin) {
    int n;
    iss >> n;
}
```

Now whether this is gonna be preferred over doing e.g. piping depends a lot on the environment the functions is gonna be used in, and as such requires more knowledge about your specific case.